# How to inherit One2many field in Odoo 12?

Tags: python, xml, inheritance, odoo, one2many

I've created a module "school" in which I have a One2many field "remarks_lines_ids", now I want this "remarks_lines_ids" field to be inherit in "sale" module (addons).

I tried this by the way.
#School Module........student.py

```
class StudentStudent(models.Model):
    _name = 'student.student'

    name = fields.Char(string='Name', required=True)

class RemarksLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'remarks.line'

    remarks = fields.Char(string='Remarks')
    student_id = fields.Many2one('student.student', string='Student')

class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    remarks_lines_ids = fields.One2many('remarks.line', 'student_id',
                                        string='Remarks Lines')


<!-- student_view.xml -->
<record id="sale_order_lines_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.lines.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[@name='order_lines']" position="inside">
            <notebook>
                <page string="Remarks Line">
                    <field name="remarks_lines_ids">
                        <tree string="Remarks Line">
                            <field name="remarks"/>
                        </tree>

                        <form string="Remarks Line">
                            <group>
                                <field name="remarks"/>
                            </group>
                        </form>
                    </field>
                </page>
            </notebook>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Did you add 'sale' module  and student_view.xml in manifest file ?

Comment: Yes sir, I have added it. I have also inherited char and integer fields in sale module.

Comment: you need to add  many2one field in 'remarks.line. model to 'sale.order.line'

Comment: Thanks I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

One2many relation need Many2one field in relation model ..

Try This

```
class RemarksLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'remarks.line'

    remarks = fields.Char(string='Remarks')
    student_id = fields.Many2one('student.student', string='Student')
    sale_order_line_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order.line')

class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    remarks_lines_ids = fields.One2many('remarks.line', 'sale_order_line_id',
                                        string='Remarks Lines')
```

Comment: Your code is not correct, but i bet you meant the correct thing. The One2many field's definition is wrong, the first parameter has to be the other models name, here `remarks.line` and the second parameter should be `sale_order_line_id` instead.

Comment: Good ... yes i forgot to put the correct model in One2many relation 'remarks.line. i correct the answer to be the right answer .. thanks